# Postgresql Replication fail over scenario - not able to bring back old primary as slave

Tags: postgresql, replication

I am facing issue while making old primary to standby after 1st fail over.

1st time slave has switched to master and when old master comes back it is still acting as primary.

I am using repmgr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to check if the slave is properly promoted to master by using

```
$ repmgr -f /etc/repmgr.conf cluster show
```

If it is not promoted, then please use

```
$ repmgr -f /etc/repmgr.conf standby promote
```

And when the old master comes back and still acting as primary, then use the switchover command (must be run from the standby which is to be promoted)

```
$ repmgr -f /etc/repmgr.conf standby switchover
```